# Why does a $C^{*}$-algebra with identity have no two-sided ideals at all?

Tags: abstract-algebra, c-star-algebras

I'm reading [Robinson & Bratteli's book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540170938) and, at some point, the following statement is given.

> A $C^{*}$-algebra $\mathcal{U}$ is called simple if it has no nontrivial closed two-sided ideals, i.e., if the only closed two-sided ideals are $\{0\}$ and $\mathcal{U}$. If $\mathcal{U}$ has an identity this amounts to saying that $\mathcal{U}$ has no two-sided ideals at all, closed or not.

But why does the second statement hold? I mean, if $\mathcal{U}$ has an identity ${\bf{1}}$, why $\{0\}$ and $\mathcal{U}$ are no longer two-sided ideals? For the first, don't we still have $a0 = 0a = 0 \in \{0\}$, for every $a \in \mathcal{U}$ (and analogously for the second)?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven sorry, I don't follow. Should I change the title?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven okay, changed the title! Thanks.

Comment: The only reading that seems to make a bit of sense is if they meant: If $\mathcal U$ is a $C^*$-algebra _with identity_ then "$\mathcal U$ has no nontrivial _closed_ two-sided ideals" $\iff$ "$\mathcal U$ has no nontrivial two-sided ideals", but they forgot "nontrivial" in the latter part.